# Issues importing Watson JAVA SDK in Android

Tags: android-studio, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am looking for a example on how to create audio to text in speech to text in ibm watson api this example is now deprecated https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk and this is the new android sdk now https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk but there is no source code about how can i create audio to text only microphone have i need your help please

i tried all of this but i cannot created this is java sdk example i don't know how can i import this to android their is so many errors https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/speech_to_text/v1 i tried that all i don't know where to start

Comment: Let us know what errors do you face exactly and try to solve them one by one.

Comment: record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    InputStream audio = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/SoundRecorder/ian_1.mp3");
                    getRecognizeOptions(audio);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

Comment: private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions(InputStream captureStream) {
         RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                 .audio(captureStream)
                 .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_MP3)
                .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
                .interimResults(true)
                .inactivityTimeout(2000)
                .speakerLabels(true)
                .build();
        SpeechRecognitionResults transcript = speechService.recognize(options).execute();
        System.out.println(transcript);

Comment: i just that code is refering by this https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/speech-to-text i am try to use websocket or can you suggest what is nice to use on audio file to text i am using ibm watson speech to text api

Comment: my application is stopped when i clicking the record button

Comment: Is this issue solved? I saw another post from you which seems to be the next stage of this. If not, and that issue is a part of this issue, then **edit your question** here or **add a link to the new question** here. If this issue is solved, mark this issue close with appropriate answer :)

Comment: No sir i posted many question here because i needed your help :( i cannot see any reference in new method to do it :(

Comment: You'd better update the question itself instead of adding comments.